# AWS EC2 export-image Task Fails with Error "Unsupported architecture 183 for 6.2.0-1017-aws"

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, amazon-ami

I am attempting to export an AMI to a VMDK file using the AWS CLI export-image command. The command I'm using is as follows:

```
aws ec2 export-image --image-id <ami-id> --disk-image-format VMDK --s3-export-location S3Bucket=<bucket-name>,S3Prefix=exports/
```

However, shortly after the export task starts, it gets cancelled, and I receive the following error message:

```
ClientError: Unsupported architecture 183 for 6.2.0-1017-aws
```

**Image Details:**

- Architecture: x86_64
- Platform: Linux/UNIX

I've searched for documentation for this specific error and what "architecture 183" refers to but haven't found anything relevant. My goal is to export this AMI as a VMDK file for use in a VMware environment.